# Task failed ELB health checks in target group

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I am using AWS ECS Fargate container to push a simple react image to it.
The Dockerfile for this is

```
FROM node:alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN echo `pwd`
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.19
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm -rf ./*
EXPOSE 3000
COPY --from=build /app/build .
```

I can run this container locally docker run -p 3000:80

But when I push this to AWS, when the ECS Service is being created its failing with the error

*Task failed ELB health checks in (target-group arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:1234567:targetgroup/dev-demo-ecs-poc-ui-alb-tg-1/bd9244f4ebc5b95a)*

In my AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition, I've

```
PortMappings:
  - ContainerPort: 3000
    Protocol: tcp
```

In my AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup, I've

```
SecurityGroupIngress:
  - IpProtocol: tcp
   FromPort: '1'
   ToPort: '65535'
   CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
VpcId: !Ref VPC
```

My AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer is referring to the above security group.

The AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup has Port:'3000' and HealthCheckPort: '3000'

The AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener has

```
LoadBalancerArn: !Ref AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
Port: 3000
Protocol: "HTTP"
```

I think something wrong about the port mapping in my Docker image, but just can't figure out the source of the pbm.

Comment: The Docker Hub `nginx` image usually listens on the standard HTTP port 80, not port 3000.  The Dockerfile `EXPOSE` directive doesn't really do anything.  The ECS `ContainerPort` probably matches the _second_ `docker run -p` port number, which needs to be 80.

Comment: So, should I change my port for the security group in the load balancer?  and/or should I change my Dockerfile?

Comment: Changing ContainerPort to 80 worked. Thanks